# How to toggle display on content using multiple Bootstrap 4 display classes in concert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm struggling to find a clean way to click toggle the display of a side navigation bar while using several of Bootstrap 4's display classes because of their use of !important.

For example, Here's an example div using the display classes I want to toggle the display on.

```
<div class="module-name d-none d-lg-block sb-collapsable">
     {{module_name}}
</div>>
```

Maybe I'm being really dense right now, but I can't find a clean way to toggle this display because of the fact that both the d-none and d-lg-block classes uses display: none/block !important. The sb-collapsable class is there as a helper to find all the things I want to hide in jQuery. I would really appreciate any help. I've tried a ton of different stuff and searched around for similar problems and haven't come up with anything.

Edit: I should add that not every div using the sb-collapsable class has the same classes on it. Here is another example. I need to toggle visibility of both this and the other div not knowing the state of display before the JS executes, ideally.

```
<a class="d-block d-lg-none brand bg-dark sb-collapsable" href="#">XXX</a>
```

Comment: Just don't use `d-none` and `d-lg-block`. Use `myOwn-d-none` and `myOwn-d-lg-block`. Ever since Bootstrap decided to use `!important` to enforce display on elements, the two classes above (and similar) have become *standard Bootstrap v4 classes*.

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled upon the same issue and coded a simple solution for it, named `bs4_display.js` (full code on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/dmarcelino/19d5297b3408331183ba8e265018c6cb)). When hiding elements it swaps any `d-*-block` classes for dummy ones like `dummy-*-block`. If afterwards you choose to show that element it does the opposite, restoring the original classes. Full working example at [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/lixikicine/edit?html,js,output). The API is:

```
bs4Display.show([HTMLelement]);
bs4Display.hide([HTMLelement]);
bs4Display.reset([HTMLelement]);
```

```js
(function(window){
  'use strict';

  // wrapper
  function bs4Display() {
    var _bs4Display = {};

    _bs4Display.DUMMY_PREFIX = 'dummy'

    // private methods
    _bs4Display._build_block_classes = function () {
      if (_bs4Display._displayBlocks) {
        return _bs4Display._displayBlocks;
      }
      var prefix = _bs4Display.DUMMY_PREFIX;
      _bs4Display._blockArray = [
        ['d-block',    prefix + '-block'],
        ['d-sm-block', prefix + '-sm-block'],
        ['d-md-block', prefix + '-md-block'],
        ['d-lg-block', prefix + '-lg-block'],
        ['d-xl-block', prefix + '-xl-block']
      ];
      _bs4Display._noneArray = [
        [prefix + '-none',    'd-none'],
        [prefix + '-sm-none', 'd-sm-none'],
        [prefix + '-md-none', 'd-md-none'],
        [prefix + '-lg-none', 'd-lg-none'],
        [prefix + '-xl-none', 'd-xl-none']
      ];
      _bs4Display._displayBlocks = _bs4Display._blockArray.concat(_bs4Display._noneArray);
      return _bs4Display._displayBlocks;
    }

    if (typeof(document.querySelector('body').classList.replace) !== 'undefined') {
      // native replace
      _bs4Display._replace = function (el, oldClass, newClass) {
        return el.classList.replace(oldClass, newClass);
      }
    } else {
      // polyfill, since support is not great:
      // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Browser_compatibility
      _bs4Display._replace = function (el, oldClass, newClass) {
        if (el.classList.contains(oldClass)) {
          el.classList.remove(oldClass);
          el.classList.add(newClass);
        }
      }
    }

    // public methods
    /**
     * Hides a HTML element with BootStrap 4 markup
     * @param {Element|[Element]} els - HTML element(s) to hide.
     */
    _bs4Display.hide = function (els) {
      if (!els) { return; }  // nothing to hide
      if (!(els instanceof Array)) { els = [els]; }
      var dBlocks = _bs4Display._build_block_classes();
      for (var k = 0; k < els.length; k++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < dBlocks.length; i++) {
          _bs4Display._replace(els[k], dBlocks[i][0], dBlocks[i][1]);
        }
        els[k].style.display = 'none';
      }
    }

    /**
     * Shows a HTML element with BootStrap 4 markup
     * @param {Element|[Element]} els - HTML element(s) to show.
     */
    _bs4Display.show = function (els) {
      if (!els) { return; }  // nothing to show
      if (!(els instanceof Array)) { els = [els]; }
      var dBlocks = _bs4Display._build_block_classes();
      for (var k = 0; k < els.length; k++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < dBlocks.length; i++) {
          _bs4Display._replace(els[k], dBlocks[i][1], dBlocks[i][0]);
        }
        els[k].style.display = '';
      }
    }

    /**
     * Restores the HTML elements original display classes
     * @param {Element|[Element]} els - HTML element(s) to reset.
     */
    _bs4Display.reset = function (els) {
      if (!els) { return; }  // nothing to show
      if (!(els instanceof Array)) { els = [els]; }
      _bs4Display._build_block_classes();
      for (var k = 0; k < els.length; k++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < _bs4Display._blockArray.length; i++) {
          _bs4Display._replace(els[k], _bs4Display._blockArray[i][1], _bs4Display._blockArray[i][0]);
          _bs4Display._replace(els[k], _bs4Display._noneArray[i][0], _bs4Display._noneArray[i][1]);
        }
        els[k].style.display = '';
      }
    }

    return _bs4Display;
  }

  if(typeof(window.bs4Display) === 'undefined') {
    window.bs4Display = bs4Display();
  }
})(window);

// optional, change prefix before first call
// window.bs4Display.DUMMY_PREFIX = 'bs4-display'
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>BootStrap 4 Show/Hide</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <p>
    <button onclick="bs4Display.show(document.getElementById('none'));" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Show d-none</button>
    <button onclick="bs4Display.hide(document.getElementById('none'));" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Hide d-none</button>
    <button onclick="bs4Display.reset(document.getElementById('none'));" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Reset d-none</button>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button onclick="bs4Display.show(document.getElementById('block'));" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Show d-block</button>
    <button onclick="bs4Display.hide(document.getElementById('block'));" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Hide d-block</button>
    <button onclick="bs4Display.reset(document.getElementById('block'));" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Reset d-block</button>
  </p>
  
  <div class="container">
  <div id="none" class="d-none p-2 bg-primary text-white">d-none</div>
  <div id="block" class="d-block p-2 bg-dark text-white">d-block</div>
    
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```